# Can an HTML dropdown be styled?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using mvc4 with the Razor engine.  Here's what I've tried:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.NewSymbol.Category.Id, new SelectList(Model.MarketCategories, "Id","Name"), new { @class = "dropdown" })
</div>
```

CSS is:

```
.dropdown {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 3px 2px;
    width: 312px; 
}

option {
    width: 312px !important;
}
```

Unfortunately I get something that looks like:
[image]

I am trying to get the drop down to be at least the same width as the 'select' element.  I don't mind if it's wider if the text expands past 312px, but this narrow drop down looks goofy.

Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `<select>` html tag you will be a the mercy of the browser for displaying and behavior. The only way around this is to make your own, or used a toolkit dropdown like [the jQuery UI one](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox).

Comment: That is unfortunate.  Thank you for the jQuery suggestion.  However the added complexity of that solution is not worth it for my particular situation (given it's an aesthetic issue, not a functional one).

Comment: Now why is there a restriction on when you can mark something as an answer?  I will give you credit in 3min as per stackoverflows restrictions.

Comment: This is a battle I fight from time to time, as the browser loves to make the width of the dropdown the max width of all the options, and I usually end up trimming the options down. Sorry there isn't more that can be done. Unless someone else knows something I dont.